# subprocess.popen for pip freeze isn't returning list of packages

Tags: python

My code appeared to have been working but now I am just receiving stdout saying,

```
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Here is my code

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

output, err = proc.communicate()
string_file = StringIO.StringIO(output)
print string_file.readlines()
```

My goal here is to get the version number for a few different packages and perform some action if the version number differs from what I previously recorded for the package's version in a json file. A subprocess of pip list does not seem to help either.

Does anyone know what may be causing this behavior or if there is an easier way for me to perform this action? I have about 10 packages I would like to check.

Comment: Interestingly enough, adding shell=true arg to the popen object works. Weird since it typically only needs to be used with shell built ins

Comment: Doesn't that message go to stderr instead? You're redirecting stderr to stdout, for some reason. Ignore stderr (but check the return value) and you may get rid of the extra lines.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do is to take `pip`'s advice and update it. If you can't do that, the error message should be harmless - the checks `pip` performs don't usually stop it from working.

You can disable the version check by using

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pip', 'freeze', '--disable-pip-version-check'],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: I'm required to keep the current pip version number for internal package purposes

Comment: Yes, I figured your environment may be constrained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the pkg_resources module to get these informations:

```
import pkg_resources
from subprocess import call

# If you want to skip some packages
exception = ['scipy', 'numpy']

# List comprehension to get the packages
pack_names = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set
    if d.project_name not in exception]

# print the package names and versions
for dist in pack_names:
    print('PACKAGE: {}'.format(dist))
    # And if you want to upgrade this package:
    call('pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir ' + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this solution only shows the following packages for me, PACKAGE: wheel 0.29.0
PACKAGE: setuptools 28.8.0
PACKAGE: pip 9.0.1

Comment: Weird...what version of python are you using  and how did you install your packages?

Comment: 2.7.14 and I installed them all with pip. No need to worry, I have found a fix. The shell=True arg seems to be holding up